# I have arrays stored in a json object, I send them using ajax call to the server side, how to access the data?

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax, get

```
$scope.addQunatity = function(){

    var url="../php/mainPageFacture.php";

    // store data from user in the js arrays
    var quan_cls_crt=[$("#quan_cls_crt").val(),$("#quan_cls_crt2").val()];
    var quan_piece=[$("#quan_piece").val(),$("#quan_piece2").val()];
    var itemName=[$("#designList").val(),$("#designList2").val()];
    var dechargementNote=[$("#dechargementNote").val(),$("#dechargementNote2").val()];
    var itemIds=[78,75];


    var func="addQunatity";

    var data = {"function": func,
                "quan_cls_crt":quan_cls_crt,
                "itemId":itemIds,
                "dechargementNote":dechargementNote,
                "quan_piece":quan_piece}; 
    data = JSON.stringify(data);

    var options = {
            type : "get",
            url : url,
            data: {data:data},
            dataType: 'json',
            async : false,
            cache : false,
            success : function(response,status) {
                debugger;
                $scope.getAllItemNames();
                alert("success");
            },
            error:function(request,response,error){
                alert("Error: " + error + ". Please contact developer");
            }
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    }
```

Here is my php code that will receive the Json object

```
           function addQunatity(){
              $quan_cls_crt = $_GET["quan_cls_crt"];
              $quan_piece = $_GET["quan_piece"];
              $itemId=$_GET['itemId'];
              $dechargementNote=$_GET['dechargementNote'];
            }
```

I expect to receive the json arrays and store them in php variable in order to use the in the query later on, but i have no idea how to access the arrays in the json object

Comment: what error you are getting in browser network?

Comment: That PHP code reads some data and does nothing with it. It isn't reading it right though - you need to read JSON, not GET variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to stringify the data, just send it as it is - the `json` data type causes jQuery to JSON-encode it for you. Don't make another object.

```
var data = {"function": func,
            "quan_cls_crt":quan_cls_crt,
            "itemId":itemIds,
            "dechargementNote":dechargementNote,
            "quan_piece":quan_piece}; 

var options = {
        type : "get",
        url : url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        async : false,
        cache : false,
        success : function(response,status) {
            debugger;
            $scope.getAllItemNames();
            alert("success");
        },
        error:function(request,response,error){
            alert("Error: " + error + ". Please contact developer");
        }
    };
    $.ajax(options);
}
```

Comment: well, but in the server side how to receive the json object and store it in variables? please can you write an example show how to get access to each item (items are actully arrays) stored in the json object and then  store it in a php variables?

Comment: you can just retrieve them from $_GET and $_POST variable depending upon method type. does not matter data is an array or any other data type.

Answer (score 0):

Dont stringify the data. Use your same code and remove the stringify line.

```
var url="../php/mainPageFacture.php";

// store data from user in the js arrays
var quan_cls_crt=[$("#quan_cls_crt").val(),$("#quan_cls_crt2").val()];
var quan_piece=[$("#quan_piece").val(),$("#quan_piece2").val()];
var itemName=[$("#designList").val(),$("#designList2").val()];
var dechargementNote=[$("#dechargementNote").val(),$("#dechargementNote2").val()];
var itemIds=[78,75];


var func="addQunatity";

var data = {"function": func,
            "quan_cls_crt":quan_cls_crt,
            "itemId":itemIds,
            "dechargementNote":dechargementNote,
            "quan_piece":quan_piece}; 

var options = {
        type : "get",
        url : url,
        data: {data:data},
        dataType: 'json',
        async : false,
        cache : false,
        success : function(response,status) {
            debugger;
            $scope.getAllItemNames();
            alert("success");
        },
        error:function(request,response,error){
            alert("Error: " + error + ". Please contact developer");
        }
    };
    $.ajax(options);
}
```

In the PHP side, like you have done -

```
          $quan_cls_crt = $_GET["quan_cls_crt"];
          $quan_piece = $_GET["quan_piece"];
          $itemId=$_GET['itemId'];
          $dechargementNote=$_GET['dechargementNote'];
```

And to access each of the values from array you can simply do that with $quan_cls_crt[0] or $quan_cls_crt[1]

Comment: $jsonObj =$_GET['whatever json variable'];

if the json name in the js file is options, then should this be in this form?

>> $jsonObj =$_GET['options']; ?

Comment: Welcome. Accept this answer then :)

Comment: sorry but your code didn't work perfectly since i have to cross out 
" data: {data:data}," and rewrite it in this form  data: data instead, and thanks  a lot for your participation

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$received_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($received_data);
//Here now you can access 
$variable_name = $data['keyname']; //this means instead of $_GET or $_POST or $_REQUEST
?>
```

You can access received json data to php using the file_get_contents('php://input'); method..